# Multi row to single row manipulation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a whole bunch of data in Excel that looks like this:

`Address     Bins
address1    94 Gallon
address1    60 Gallon
address1    94 Gallon
address1    35 Gallon
address1    94 Gallon
address1    35 Gallon
address1    60 Gallon
address1    94 Gallon`

I want to eliminate rows with the same address and merge them into one row like so.

`Address    Bin1    Bin2    Bin3    Bin4    Bin5    Bin6    Bin7    Bin8
address1    94 Gallon   60 Gallon   94 Gallon   35 Gallon   94 Gallon   35 Gallon   60 Gallon   94 Gallon`

How would I do this?

Comment: Do you have multiple addresses? How many columns per address can you have?

Comment: Yes there are multiple addresses on the spreadsheet.  Up to 20 bins per one address.

Comment: Then my macro answer should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all the bins for each address in a single row using formulas need to:

1. Add a column to the sample table at column `A` named Key (see Fig. 1)

[image]
Fig. 1

**Key**: Used to retrieve the corresponding *bins* for each *Address*

*Enter this formula in `A2` then copy to the last record*

```
=CONCATENATE($B2,".",COUNTIF($B$1:$B2,$B2))
```

2. Add a range starting at `E1` to list the *address\bin* table (see Fig. 2)

[image]

Fig. 2

**Address**: Extracts unique values from column `B`

*Enter this as `Formula Array` in `E2` then copy to the last record*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$22,
MATCH(SUM(COUNTIF(E$1:E1,$B$2:$B$22)),
COUNTIF($B$2:$B$22,"<"&$B$2:$B$22),0)),"")}
```

**Count**: Count of bins per address. Use this to extent the width of the table

*Enter this formula in `F2` then copy to the last record*

```
=IF(EXACT($E2,""),"",COUNTIF($B:$B,$E2))
```

**Bin.1 to Bin.n**: Contents of bins

*Enter this formula in `G2` then copy to the last record for all bins*

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE($E2,".",RIGHT(G$1)),$A:$C,3,0),"")
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I add this to e2 cell.  What am I doing wrong? {=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$22,
MATCH(SUM(COUNTIF(F$1:F1,$B$2:$B$22)),
COUNTIF($B$2:$B$22,"<"&$B$2:$B$22),0)),"")}

Comment: I think this will work for me if I could only get it to work in my excel spreadsheet

Comment: are you entering it as array formula? notice that the formula to be entered is without brackets: `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$22, MATCH(SUM(COUNTIF(F$1:F1,$B$2:$B$22)), COUNTIF($B$2:$B$22,"<"&$B$2:$B$22),0)),"")` the brackets will be add as it’s entered correctly as an array formula. To enter as Array formula enter the formula in the cell and press `[Ctrl+Shift+Enter]`. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Ok this works if I change this range $B$2:$B$22 for each set of addresses.  However your post says to just drag it down and it will produce the results in your SS.  I cant get that to work unless I change the B range. Thank you. Otherwise it just pulls one address all the way down the column.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work when there is only one address as well.

Comment: Please let me know into what did you change $B$2:$B$22?

Comment: something is definitely wrong, just tested with only one address and it works fine. did you enter the formula as array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89719/discussion-between-eem-and-eric).

Comment: Once the bins go over 9 it seems the bin field 10 is left blank and the bins repeat. Going up to 100 bin fields on the spreadsheet.  If there are 6 bins total it will fill bin11 - 17 with bin information and do that for 21-27 all the way to 100.  Is there some way to fix this?  It appears to be looking at the second number but I have no excel knowledge and cant fix it without your help.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the rows.  Copy.  When you paste, right click so see options.  Go with the one that transposes the data.  It will paste it all in columns instead of a row.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should take your addresses and combine them. After that, you just need to add your column headers

```
Sub ConsolidateRows_MultipleCells()
'takes rows and consolidate one or many cells, based on one or many cells matching with above or below rows.

Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim colMatch As Variant, colConcat As Variant, lColDest As Long

'**********PARAMETERS TO UPDATE****************
Const strMatch As String = "A"    'columns that need to match for consolidation, separated by commas
Const strConcat As String = "B"     'columns that need consolidating, separated by commas
Const lDest As Long = 2     'starting column for the consolidated items
'*************END PARAMETERS*******************

application.ScreenUpdating = False 'disable ScreenUpdating to avoid screen flashes

colMatch = Split(strMatch, ",")
colConcat = Split(strConcat, ",")

Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Cells(1, colMatch(0)), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:= _
                    False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2 _
                    :=xlSortNormal


lastRow = range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row

lColDest = lDest

For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1 'loop from last Row to one

    For j = 0 To UBound(colMatch)
        If Cells(i, colMatch(j)) <> Cells(i - 1, colMatch(j)) Then
            lColDest = lDest
            GoTo nxti
        End If
    Next

    For j = 0 To UBound(colConcat)
        range(Cells(i, strConcat), Cells(i, 1).End(xlToRight)).Copy Cells(i - 1, 1).End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1)
        lColDest = lColDest + 1
    Next

    Rows(i).Delete

nxti:
Next

application.ScreenUpdating = True 'reenable ScreenUpdating
End Sub
```